# Bootstrap 3.3.7 Dropdown not displaying selected value

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal

I am new to Bootstrap and I'm Working with the latest **Bootstrap 3.3.7**.
I'm trying to display the selected value when the user selects one of the options. but using my below code its not displaying selected value can some one help me please

## html:

```
 <div class="form-group">
   <label for="department">DepartMent</label>
   <select id="department" name="department" [(ngModel)]="department" class="form-control">
     <option *ngFor="let dept of departments" [value]="dept">
       {{dept.name}}
     </option>
   </select>
 </div>
```

### .ts:

```
departments: Department[] = [
    { id: 1, name: 'HR' },
    { id: 2, name: 'IT' },
    { id: 3, name: 'DEV'},
    { id: 4, name: 'MG' }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace this '[value]="dept"' to **[value]="dept.id"**.

Comment: value id is binding but its not displaying

Comment: see this working example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n4mw2y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: apply class="form-control" then its not displaying

Comment: provided link, it is displaying with form-control class. Please let me know what is the exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change
**[value]** to **value** and
**"dept.id"** to **{{dept.id}}**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="department">DepartMent</label>
    <select id="department" name="department" [(ngModel)]="department" class="form-control">
      <option selected disabled>Select a Department</option>
      <option  value={{dept.id}} *ngFor="let dept of departments">
       {{dept.name}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```